# MySQL Drops Connection After Consecutive Queries

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, networking

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? It started happening after I implemented mysql_multi to run multiple instances of the MySQL service (one on port 3306, one on port 3307). I'm running MySQL on Ubuntu server.

Here's what happens:

```
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
Operation failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.40' (10061)
Fetching table list.
Operation failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.40' (10061)
Fetching table list.
Operation failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.40' (10061)
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Fetching table list.
    63 items from dbname
OK
Fetching view list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching routine list.
    0 items from dbname
OK
Fetching trigger list.
Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Comment: I have no idea why this was happening. I reformatted the disk and reinstalled the latest version of Ubuntu and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you had set the timeout to low on my.cnf